# Calling a C# class from my ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, class

I have an ASPX page that is the web form that is handling the design and code behind. I was told that all the classes that I have in this page need to broken up into their own files. Those files need to have the same name as the class name. My ASPX file is default.aspx, and my class is GetMachineInfo.cs. How do I call that cs file in my ASPX file, so that it is like my class is inside of the ASPX page.I will insert some code if you need it. I cut some code out in order to focus on the actual issue. If there is a curly brace missing or something its because of that. Just wanted to give the necessary information for this specific problem. Cheers.

```js
namespace PVDA.Web
{
    /*
   * LINQ Queries for binding
   * This is calling the wrong information
   * It's calling the n attribute of "srn", not the mach "n"
   * This is going a layer too deep. needs to be mach no srn
   */

    public class Machine
    {

        // Getting all the objects to the machine
        public int snsrN { get; set; }
        public string calctype { get; set; }
        public string sensName { get; set; }


        public static List<Machine> GetMachineInfo(XDocument xDoc, int machineNumber)
        {

            return xDoc.XPathSelectElements("./mmsdata/mill/mach")
                               .Where(x => x.Attribute("n").Value == machineNumber.ToString())
                               .Elements()
                               .Select(x => new Machine
                               {
                                   sensName = x.Value,
                                   snsrN = Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("n").Value),
                                   calctype = x.Attribute("calctype").Value
                               }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

```html
namespace PVDA.Web
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Calling
                ddlBinding();
                NewQuery();
            }

           
           
        }

  public void ddlBinding()
        {
            // Getting the XML file imported in
            const string FILE_PATH = @"MillData.xml";
            // Set the file path
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(FILE_PATH));


            Machine machine = new Machine();


            // Setting a variable to bind the data into the dropdownlists
            var dropDownDataList1 = GetMillInfo(xDoc, "n");
            var dropDownDataList2 = machine.GetMachineInfo(xDoc, 2);

 // Bind Machines to DropDownList2
            DropDownList2.DataSource = machine.GetMachineInfo(xDoc, 2);
            // Set text / value properties
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "snsrN";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "sensName";
            // Bind the contents to be reflected in the UI
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `GetMachineInfo()` method is defined in the same namespace as your form (i.e. PVDA.Web), you should be able to call it as expected, however methods are required to be defined within a class and not directly under a namespace.

As a result you may want to consider marking them as `static` to allow them to be called without explicitly instantiating an instance of your class :

```
public class Machine
{
    public static List<Machine> GetMachineInfo(XDocument xDoc, int machineNumber)
    {
        // Omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

This would allow you to call this method throughout your application through `Machine.GetMachineInfo(...)`, which you could do within any of the pages in your application :

```
// Within your ddlBinding() method
DropDownList2.DataSource = Machine.GetMachineInfo(xDoc, 2);
```

Comment: Still getting an error that _defualt.Machine does not contain a definition for GetMachineInfo with "DropDownList2.DataSource = Machine.GetMachineInfo(xDoc, 2); and also its not finding XDocument in GetMachineInfo, or any of the variables... I think its something simple that I just forgot to add honestly

Comment: You need to ensure that you are placing your binding code within an actual method (i.e. `dllBinding()`). You may also have to add the appropriate using statements within your external definition to ensure that it can access the proper classes it needs. Try right-clicking on the XDocument class and checking for a "Resolve" option in Visual Studio, which should add the appropriate using statement automatically. You will likely want to include your `Machine` class in a different file and reference it as well.

Comment: You can [see a Gist here demonstrated what these separated files might look like](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/708305a93bc6060b0c99efa7fb0494af).

Comment: I do in fact have the GetMachineInfo in another file, and am trying to reference back to it within my ASPX page. Would something along the lines of 'class Machine = new class();' work? The syntax doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: Try using the `static` approach that I defined in the Gist above. It should allow you to reference the method via `MachineMethods.GetMachineInfo()` as expected. You'll need to have a `using` statement within that file pointing to the namespace where your `Machine` class is defined so that the method knows what a `Machine` object is. Additionally, if you need to create an instance of a single machine, you would use `Machine machine = new Machine();`.

Comment: I edited the code, and inserted what I changed above following your guidelines. I couldn't get MachineMethods.GetMachineInfo(); to work. Still getting an error passing xDoc, and it wont find XDocument in the seperate file that I have

Comment: Did you include a using statement for the `XDocument` class? It should be  `using System.Xml.Linq;` at the top of that file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate .cs file for class. It's best practice to have file name and class name are the same. It will be easy to track and if you want to modify any functionality just you can goto the file and modify.

1. create a separate file for class
2. Remove the class def inside the aspx page
3. Add the class namespace in aspx page
4. Instantiate the class
      Ex. `class CLS = new class();`

Comment: Yeah, went into a code review and they told me to make this change to my classes. this is exactly what I am looking to do. Where should I place the instatiation. Plus when I try that snippet of code with my class name inserted I am getting an error.